# Is there an indexable way to store several bitfields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which needs to store several bitfields...

- **notification.id** -- autonumber int
- **association.id** -- BIT FIELD 1 -- stores one or more association ids (which are obtained from another table)
- **type.id** -- BIT FIELD 2 -- stores one or more types that apply to this notification (again, obtained from another table)
- **notification.day_of_week** -- BIT FIELD 3 -- stores one or more days of the week
- **notification.target** -- where to send the notification -- data type is irrelevant, as we'll never index or sort on this field, but
  will probably store an email address.

My users will be able to configure their notifications to trigger on one or more days, in one or more associations, for one or more types. I need a quick, indexable way to store this data.

Bit fields 1 and 2 can expand to have more values than they do presently. Currently 1 has values as high as 125, and 2 has values as high as 7, but both are expected to go higher.

Bit field 3 stores days of the week, and as such, will always have only 7 possible values.

I'll need to run a script frequently (every few minutes) that scans this table based on type, association, and day, to determine if a given notification should be sent. Queries need to be fast, and the simpler it is to add new data, the better. I'm not above using joins, subqueries, etc as needed, but I can't imagine these being faster.

One last requirement -- if I have 1000 different notifications stored in here, with 125 association possibilities, 7 types, and 7 days of the week, the combination of records is too high for my taste if just using integers, and storing multiple copies of the row, instead of using bit fields, so it seems like using bit fields is a requirement.

However, from what I've heard, if I wanted to select everything from a particular day of the week, say Tuesday (b0000100 in a bit field, perhaps), bit fields are not indexed such that I can do...

```
SELECT * FROM \`mydb\`.\`mytable\` WHERE \`notification.day_of_week\` & 4 = 4;
```

This, from my understanding, would not use an index at all.

Any suggestions on how I can do this, or something similar, in an indexable fashion?

(I work on a pretty standard LAMP stack, and I'm looking for specifics on how the MySQL indexing works on this or a similar alternative.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no "good" way (that I know of) to accomplish what you want to.
Note that the BIT datatype is limited to a size of 64 bits.

For bits that can be statically defined, MySQL provides the SET datatype, which is in some ways the same as BIT, and in other ways it is different.

For days of the week, for example, you could define a column

```
dow SET('SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT')
```

There's no builtin way (that I know of of getting the internal bit represntation back out, but you can add a 0 to the column, or cast to unsigned, to get a decimal representation.

```
SELECT dow+0, CONVERT(dow,UNSIGNED), dow, ...

1  1  SUN
2  2  MON
3  3  SUN,MON
4  4  TUE
5  5  SUN,TUE
6  6  MON,TUE
7  7  SUN,MON,TUE
```

It is possible for MySQL to use a "covering index" to satisfy a query with a predicate on a SET column, when the SET column is the leading column in the index. (i.e. EXPLAIN shows 'Using where; Using index') But MySQL may be performing a full scan of the index, rather than doing a range scan. (And there may be differences between the MyISAM engine and the InnoDB engine.)

```
SELECT id FROM notification WHERE FIND_IN_SET('SUN',dow)

SELECT id FROM notification WHERE (dow+0) MOD 2 = 1
```

BUT... this usage is non-standard, and can't really be recommended. For one thing, this behavior is not guaranteed, and MySQL may change this behavior in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit more research on this, and realized there's no way to get the indexing to work as I outlined above. So, I've created an auxiliary table (somewhat like the WordPress meta table format) which stores entries for day of week, etc. I'll just join these tables as needed. Fortunately, I don't anticipate having more than ~10,000 entries at present, so it should join quickly enough.

I'm still interested in a better answer if anyone has one!